# Using Angular and Node.js to build a commercial website

Tags: licensing

I plan to build a commercial website in Angular 5. Can I do so without needing to pay anyone?

It looks like the node.js license consists of a lot of other components and each of them has their own set of paragraphs. Do I need to list any licenses on my website to give credit to the developers?

I tried to go through the license agreements but did not get very far before I started to not understand most of the jargon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it without paying anyone. Angular is published under the terms of the MIT license, which contains the phrase "free of charge". This holds for almost everything you could do with it.

See [here](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license) for further details on the license.

Comment: This is an awesome website. Thanks!